# how to add string with quotes and slashes in golang

Tags: go

I'll share an example

I want the line below in golang string  `curl -u admin:admin -H 'Accept: application/yang-data+json' -s http://<ip>/restconf/data/ -v`

code I wrote:

cmd := `"curl -u admin:admin -H 'Accept: application/yang-data+json' -s http://" + ip_string + "/restconf/data/ -v"`

err:
unexpected string at the end of Line.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that produces the issue

Comment: Please make sure to faithfully paste the code in question.  Place the entire line in a block of code deliniated by triple-backtick "```".  Don't otherwise change the line .  I can't tell whether the backticks are or ar not part of the `cmd` setting

Comment: Aside from the fact that `Go` has a very powerful `net/http` package for making http calls... If you are using the `os/exec` package to run a command, the `cmd` should be listed separately from its input arguments (which should be listed in a string slice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unexpected string at the end of Line.

You can use `fmt.Sprintf` to format a string so that you don't have to stitch it together by hand.  I find this easier to read and write, myself:

```
fmt.Sprintf("curl -u admin:admin -H 'Accept: application/yang-data+json' -s http://%s/restconf/data/ -v", ip_string)
```

Seems like you're trying to create a shell command to invoke Curl. Better than trying to escape your `curl` arguments for the shell, is to invoke `curl` directly.   This way you can use Go to separate the arguments without having to worry about shell quoting:

```
cmd := exec.Command("curl", 
   "-u", "admin:admin",
   "-H", "Accept: application/yang-data+json",  
   "-s", 
   fmt.Sprintf("http://%s/restconf/data/", ip_string), 
   "-v",
)
```

However, if I were you, I'd use https://pkg.go.dev/net/http to make the request and obviate `os/exec` entirely.  Performance and efficiency will be better, and handling the response and any error conditions will be *way* easier than doing that through `curl` and trying to parse output and handle error codes.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("http://%s", source_ip), nil)
// handle err
req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/yang-data+json")
req.SetBasicAuth("admin","admin")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
// handle err!
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
// handle err!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what about the flags -u -s and -v how to include that

Comment: {"error":"parse \"-s http://<ip>/restconf/data/ -v\": first path segment in URL cannot contain colon","handler":"POST /collect","jobID":"Collect-11-24-2021_051320","level":"error","method":"initiateConfdCollection","msg":"Getrunningconfig: Failed to create request: parse \"-s http://<ip>/restconf/data/ -v\": first path segment in URL cannot contain colon","time":"2021-11-24T05:13:21Z"}
{"handler":"POST /collect","jobID":"Collect-11-24-2021_051320","level":"error","method":"initiateConfdCollection","msg":"Failed to get data from Namespace: <ip>","time":"2021-11-24T05:13:21Z"}

Comment: Got the above error while using https://pkg.go.dev/net/http

Comment: If you want to go with the `net/http` approach and you are getting an error, best to paste that as a new question.   Looks to me that have `-s`, the url, and `-v` all in the same string there.